# How to event handle ALL focus() and blur() triggers on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Timer in javascript that's doing stuff in the background every xxx seconds. however the ajax work in the background seems to interrupt the users typing. I fix this by disabling the timers when focus/blur like one would, however, how can i make this site wide?

I want a way to magically detect any focus/blur events happening in any inputbox/textarea element and call some code, for both blur and focus.. is there a way to achieve this that will work without individually settings up the handlers for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
$('input, textarea').on({
    focus: function(e) {
        // ...
    },
    blur: function(e) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

If you want same function for both events then (probably you don't want this):

```
$('input, textarea').on('focus blur', function(e) {
    // ...
});
```